# symfony 4 - Custom error page & custom error message

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I want to create my custom error page (404, 403, etc.) in Symfony 4 so I have exception, e.g.

```
if (!$thisVarIsNull) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException(
        'This is my custom message'
    );
}
```

and I have created basic template in location `templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error.html.twig`:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block title %}
    We got a problem
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <div>
        <p>
            {{ status_code }} :: {{ exception.message }}
        </p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

but the `exception.message` does not return anything. Where is the problem?

Comment: You really want to print the exception to the user? In my opinion a very bad idea ... Did you set a breakpoint to see whats happen?

Comment: Try dumping {{ exception }} to see it's contents.

Comment: @JimPanse Ok, I need to show 2 errors: Not Found specific record and "checking" has return false. How should I do this?

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is `{{ status_message }}` instead of `{{ exception.message }}`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I checked over docs. There is no variable **exception**.

You can only get 2 things

- CODE - {{ status_code }}
- STATUS_TEXT - {{ status_text }}

---

**Additionally**

error.html.twig will be rendered when you get all erros except 404/403

Please also create templates for 404/403 (in same folder), otherwise the default ones will be rendered.

- error404.html.twig
- error403.html.twig

---

You can easily test everything in development by using /_error/{statusCode}...

For example: yoursite.com/_error/404

Comment: I am pretty sure there is indeed a variable for the exception message. It isn't documented because usually you don't want to print a error message to the frontend-user directly.